# Expression into jsp:include

Tags: java, jsp

Is there a way to do something like this in JSP :

```
<% String path = session.getAttribute("path").toString(); %>
<jsp:include page="<%=path%>/vue/includes/header.jsp"/>
```

in `path` there is `localhost:8080`

Thanks,

I have an error : **`attribute for %>" is not properly terminated`**

Here is the code :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<jsp:useBean id="User" class="metier.User"/>
<jsp:useBean id="Pays" class="metier.Pays"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="User" property="login" param="login"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="User" property="pass" param="pass"/>
<% String path = session.getAttribute("path").toString(); %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:include page="<%=path%>/vue/includes/header.jsp"/>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <c:forEach var="p" items="${Pays.getPays()}"> 
            <a href="<%=path%>/vue/team.jsp?idPays=${p.idPays}"><c:out value="${p.name}"/></a><br/>
        </c:forEach>
        <jsp:include page="<%=path%>/vue/includes/footer.jsp"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

`header.jsp` is just an HTML file

PS : I am a beginner in JSP

Comment: try to post all the code

Comment: what is your header.jsp doing with user?

Comment: @Abdelhak I have explained.. Hope that you will understand me

Comment: Does your `path` point to the right location?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<% String path = session.getAttribute("path").toString();
   String url = "http://" + path + "/vue/includes/header.jsp";
%>
<c:import url='${url}'/>
```

Comment: not working :( ! I tried to find a solution with the links but not working, do you have an idea for relative links ? Thanks

Comment: Did you try the `c:import` statement or `jsp:include` ?